# Jekyll serve changes many files in my repo

Tags: git, jekyll, github-desktop

I'm working with **jekyll** based website (my experience with jekyll is very poor) and I want to make some changes and commit. I forked and opened locally the repository and I haven't made any changes. My problem happens when I open repo in Command Prompt and use `jekyll serve`, then it appears in my GitHub Desktop that I changed more than 50 files. Added few files, deleted `_site/css/style.css`, modified few files, modified few images (which are basically the same). 
How to fix this issue? 
[Before jekyll serve command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU8rM.png)

[After jekyll serve command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIgX6.png)

[Command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxJxY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jekyll is a static website generator, each time you run the serve or build command, by default it will wipe out your _site folder and create a "new" site with your changes there.

The above folder is where the generated files are located by default. That is why git detects those changes in your file system. There is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: But when I'll commit, this changes will be committed as well, right?

Comment: If you commit the tracked changes then they will be committed (?)

Comment: I mean, my problem is that I don't want this changes. So if it's default behaviour, is there any way I can stop it? I'm contributing to a project and I'd like to commit only my changes and I need `jekyll serve` to see my changes.

Comment: You would tipically just commit the changes to source files without the _site folder, but you have to follow each project set up.